# Missing scale on ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a graph using ggplot2. Here is the first output of the graph before any tidying is done.

[image: graph]

And here is the code:

```
graph <- ggplot(data = village.times,
 aes(x=village.times$a6ncopo, y=(village.times$a5species=="funestus")))
 + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack", fill="#FF4444")
```

What I don't know is why there isn't a scale on the y axis and how to remove the True-False labels. Is there a way I can force ggplot to include a scale on the y axis or do I have to change the way I use my data?

Comment: `(village.times$a5species=="funestus")` is returning `TRUE` and `FALSE` and you get a stacked bar plot... This is at least what I guess... 
So not sure which numbers you expect on the y axis...

Comment: I am plotting the number of captured "funestus", so I was hoping to see the  numbers of "funestus" on the y axis. Without the scale it is hard to compare to other graphs.

Comment: Maybe you could create a little reproducible example. When I try to save your data structure, I get some errors and can not reproduce the whole thing.

Comment: I've replaced it with the dput from the dataframe I was using, instead of the dput from the ggplot. Maybe that will be reproducible? Let me know if this works, if not I'll make a small reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe subsetting your data frame before using ggplot and just creating a histogram? Otherwise I don't what your expected result should be...

```
ggplot(subset(village.times, a5species=="funestus"), 
       aes(x=a6ncopo)) + 
  geom_bar()
```